# How do we clear all the items from the Grid in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I am not looking at clearing all the store items with removeAll(). I have a paginated grid which has multiple pages. I want to clear out everything and before i assign new set of data , it should look afresh ? Does anyone know of any API ?

Regards

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this manually if you intend to paginate using paging toolbar.

Comment: The solution was to reload the store, using the proxy(reader) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExtJS grids are bound to an `Ext.data.Store`, all of their data comes from the store. If you want to clear the contents of a grid you'd have to clear the contents of its store.

If your data can be loaded from the same store URL with different parameters then you could try just manually overriding them when you want to load fresh data...

```
grid.getStore().load({
   params: {
      newParam: value
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The way to clear grid data(without doing a backend hit) is to clear the associated store data and refresh the grid view.

Lets say transactionsGrid is associated with a store, then we can clear data shown in grid as below:

> clear data using : `transactionsGrid.store.clearData();` 
>   then refresh the grid view as :  `transactionsGrid.view.refresh();`

Comment: `clearData()` is a private function on the Store object and should not be called directly, as it could be subject to API changes without warnings in future versions

Comment: I had use store.clearData() and it have another issue with filter grid by another grid